# How do I add multiple automatic carousels to my page?

Tags: slider, carousel, slideshow, slide

I have been trying to set up a new page and wanted to insert multiple carousels at the top. As I am rather new I would prefer CSS and HTML only. Having tried both WS3's slider and Bootstrap Carousel, they both work fine if I only add one item per page. As soon as I try to add a second slider/carousel, it stops working.
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

[Here is an image of what it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDrtc.jpg)

```html
<table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img class="mySlides1" src="images/1.jpg">
                                <img class="mySlides1" src="images/2.jpg">
                                <img class="mySlides1" src="images/3.jpg">
                            </td>

                            <td>
                                <img class="mySlides2" src="images/4.jpg">
                                <img class="mySlides2" src="images/5.jpg">
                                <img class="mySlides2" src="images/6.jpg">
                            </td>
    
                           <td>
                                <img class="mySlides3" src="images/7.jpg">
                                <img class="mySlides3" src="images/8.jpg">
                                <img class="mySlides3" src="images/9.jpg">
                            </td>

                          </tr>
                        </table>
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
 
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1", "mySlides2", "mySlides3");
 
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
       x[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > x.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    x[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
</script>
```

The thing I get is either only one carousel working or seeing images 1-9 at once.
Any help is appreciated. I am also open to use other elements to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to change to the code. Now all three carousels are changing every two seconds for four or five times and then they keep changing at a really high speed.
Need help, please.

```html
<script>
var myIndex = 0;
carousel();
 
function carousel() {
    var i;
    var xx1 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides1");
    var xx2 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides2");
    var xx3 = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides3");
 
    for (i = 0; i < xx1.length; i++) {
       xx1[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > xx1.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    xx1[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
    
     for (i = 0; i < xx2.length; i++) {
       xx2[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > xx2.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    xx2[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds

    for (i = 0; i < xx3.length; i++) {
       xx3[i].style.display = "none";  
    }
    myIndex++;
    if (myIndex > xx3.length) {myIndex = 1}    
    xx3[myIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    setTimeout(carousel, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds


}
</script>
```